# Get Facebook friends with Parse.com iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

Below is my code to get facebook friends for the user logged in.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends" parameters:@{@"fields": @"email, name, first_name, last_name, user_friends, id"}];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSArray *friendObjects = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
             NSMutableArray *friendIds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:friendObjects.count];
             // Create a list of friends' Facebook IDs
             for (NSDictionary *friendObject in friendObjects) {
                 [friendIds addObject:[friendObject objectForKey:@"id"]];
             }

             // Construct a PFUser query that will find friends whose facebook ids
             // are contained in the current user's friend list.
             PFQuery *friendQuery = [PFUser query];
             [friendQuery whereKey:@"fbId" containedIn:friendIds];
             [friendQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                 if (error) {

                 } else {
                     self.friendUsers = objects; // self.friendUsers in array
                     [self.tableView reloadData];
                 }
             }];

         }
     }];
```

Im not getting any results and im not sure why i followed the steps here https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-find-parse-users-that-are-facebook-friends-with-the-current-user

please help

Comment: Do you have any friends that are users of the same app already, and have granted it `user_friends` permission as well?

Comment: @CBroe hi non of my facebook friends are using app that explains why lol. But should the code work including this `initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"`

Comment: I guess it should (though I have little experience with Android apps). I suggest you create some test users via the app dashboard, make them friends, and then test your app using one of those.

Comment: @CBroe this is for ios not android

Comment: Ah, same difference :)

Comment: If no friends are using your app, you'll see no friends via the Graph API. Perfectly fine behavior, and also described in the docs

Answer (score 1):

The [user_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_friends) Facebook permission only returns the friends of the user that have already approved the `user_friends` permission to  the app.

> In order for a person to show up in one person's friend list, both
>   people must have decided to share their list of friends with your app
>   and not disabled that permission during login. Also both friends must
>   have been asked for user_friends during the login process. [1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)

So unless some of your Facebook friends have already approved that permission to that same app, you'll get an empty friend's list.